# Hi, I'm trying to display a normal message if one payment method is selected in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, phtml

I'm trying to display a normal message if one payment method is selected in Magento 1.9
can any one help me on that? especially the locations of the files to edit?

Comment: What message you want to show and where?

Comment: I want to show (Please make sure to enable Cookies from your browser!)

Comment: when and where?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I'm using paytabs paymentmethod(it's external)

Comment: I want it to be visible under the payment method label as an Alert... when the payment method is selected

Comment: Thats not the matter as you have a module of that payment extension in your magento installation and you can create a message according to that

Comment: True that, I just want to add the message below the payment method as in the screen shot.   https://ibb.co/n7Qj6y

Comment: Hi @SukumarGorai can you help me with that?

Comment: Yes sure. Wait I am adding one code. What checkout extension you are using?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I'm using Paytabs  extension

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: Sure.. https://www.equipus.com/

Comment: Just choose from the featured products as they are instock

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: you mean in app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml ?

Comment: yes. Also add the css I have added to your footer. Afterwards you can copy that js and css to your desired location.

Comment: OMG , you are really amazing, thanks for the answer, but there is more issue

Comment: in the chrome browser it shows the message nicely but the whole block gets down as shown https://ibb.co/hyGPOd

Comment: and in the firefox its even worse, please check the screen shot https://ibb.co/fqQZOd

Comment: Now you need to modify the css according to your requirement. I am not a frontend developer so you need to manage that section by yourself :) If you have issue related to coding then you can post I ll definitely help!

Comment: Okay, thank you alot for the great support dear SukumarGorai ..really appreciate it :)

Comment: You welcome. Happy to help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80290/discussion-on-question-by-monty-nabeel-hi-im-trying-to-display-a-normal-messag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code to your footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#co-payment-form dt input').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'paytabs_server'){
                $(this).next().append('<span id="paytab_message">Please make sure to enable Cookies from your browser!</span>')
            }else{
                $('#paytab_message').remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also add this css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #paytab_message{
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 12px;
        display: inherit;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi @Sukumar Gorai, There are 2 problems facing me now, 1: if you keep clicking on the radio button the message will be repeated.  2: I cannot translate the message to other language.